# shopware custom admin config component doesn't save sales channel id

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

For a shopware 6 plugin , in config.xml I have a custom component

```xml
<card>
    <title>My Plugin</title>
    <title lang="de-DE">My Plugin</title>
    <component name="config-component">
        <name>configComponent</name>
    </component>
</card>
```

In the twig of this component i have a simple field

```html
<sw-text-field :label="Test" size="medium" required />
```

I saw that for components, if i want to change the sales channel and save the data, the sales channel id is not saved in the `system_config` table for that text field.

What can i do so my inputs from components be dependent on sales channels? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following component and template should work as intended.

```js
import template from './config-component.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.register('config-component', {
    template,

    props: {
        value: {
            required: true,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onChange(value) {
            this.$emit('change', value || '');
        },

        onInput(value) {
            this.$emit('input', value);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<sw-text-field
    v-model="value"
    label="Test"
    size="medium"
    required
    @input="onInput"
    @change="onChange"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.In this case , the configuration_key from system_config it will be `PluginName.config.configComponent`(name from config.xml) . How can i set custom names if i have multiple <sw_text_field> in the same component?

Comment: For each instance of `<component>` in the `config.xml` there will be exactly one row in the `system_config` table. You can't have one component that covers multiple `system_config` rows. But what you could do is set up `value` as an object (add `default() { return {}; }` to the property after `required: true`) and have multiple inputs bound to keys within that object. So you'd have fields like `<sw-text-field v-model="value.field1">`. `PluginName.config.configComponent` would then be an array (in PHP) that has a key `field1` for example.